# Calculating how much nichrome wire rod is required to heat aluminium at 490°C

Tags: resistance, temperature, heat

My purpose is to install nichrome wire rod in an aluminium annealing furnace with capacity of annealing 3800kgs of aluminium.

The furnace is well insulated. It has two built in blowers to circulate the heated air within the chamber.

The dimensions of the chamber are 8ft x 5ft x 5ft.

The quantity of aluminium sheet that will be annealed is 3800kg of 1.5mm.

The limitations are:

1. The desired temperature of 490°C should be achieved within 4hours.
2. I have a electric supply of 440V
3. The blowers rotate at 1440rpm, circulating the air inside and dissipating the heat across the chamber.

I would like to know that what dimension and grade of nichrome wire rod should be installed in my furnace to achieve the desired results.

Comment: This seems like a lot to ask of Nichrome wire, why not use a furnace?

Comment: That's hundreds of sheets!! And to perform this design will require an incredible amount of detail about your intended design and procedures. There are huge edge effects for these sheets, too. Which suggests multizone control and a very carefully considered layout. It's only that much more complex if you are running blowers. I don't know about others, but I don't think there is any good chance of providing you with specific recommendations unless someone else already has gone through a very similar process to yours and already has the answers in mind. I certainly don't with so little info.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is far too involved of a project to work well on this site.

Answer (score 1):

It would look something like this
[image] with 65 kW of heat minimum.  I would use quartz heaters similar to those used in IR Reflow ovens 3 phase, highest voltage you can get.

Or this

[image]

see brochures and other docs https://www.secowarwick.com/en/products/aluminium-furnace-systems/